# jQuery and toggleClass issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've ran into an issue with a bit of javascript I have.
Basically I've created an accordion module, but, I need a toggleclass to change the name of the header div when the accordion slides open, I've looked on various places but I can't seem to get it right!

Any help on where to put the correct javascript would be GREATLY appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Here's the JS i'm using:

```
function showslidey(id, el) { 
    /* Find out if the selector is MooTools or JQuery - It Matters! */
    if (typeof jQuery == "function") {
        // JQuery   
        jQuery('#linky' + id).slideDown()
    } else {
        // Mootools
        var VerticalSlide = new Fx.Slide('linky' + id);
        // We need to start by making sure the content is hidden - it defaults to display: none
        VerticalSlide.hide();
        $('linky' + id).setStyle('display', 'block');
        // Slide in the content
        VerticalSlide.slideIn();
    }
    el.setAttribute('onclick', 'hideslidey(' + id + ',this)');
}

function hideslidey(id, el) {
    if (typeof jQuery == "function") {
        // JQuery 
        jQuery('#linky' + id).slideUp()
    } else {
        // Mootools
        var VerticalSlide = new Fx.Slide('linky' + id);
        VerticalSlide.slideOut();
    }
    el.setAttribute('onclick', 'showslidey(' + id + ',this)');
}
```

Here's the HTML i've got as well:

```
<div class="header" onclick="showslidey(<?php echo $link->link_id; ?>,this)">
    <h3></h3>

echo "<div id='linky{$link->link_id}' style='display: none;'>"; 
    ?>
```

Comment: why do you have Mootools and jQuery? Can you not have just Mootools, or just jQuery? btw, there is a php starting tag missing

Comment: Hi, at the time of writing the code i wasn't sure if it was mootools or jquery so i just put in both + i just c+p'd that one line from the php file, the code is all correct within the file i assure you

Comment: As @vladkras pointed I'm not good enough to answer on javascript questions. But I can recommend you [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). It makes exploring your code and answering your question much easier.

Comment: Is it too late to go only Mootools or only jQuery? You will save some time and you can do as much with each of them

Comment: i can use just jquery, that should make it easier

Comment: well it depends on your level of knowledge in jQuery/Mootools, but I think having just one framework will spare you time.

Comment: i have a bit more knowledge in jquery than mootools so i'll go down the jquery route; still, i'm confused on where to put the toggle class

Comment: Do you want to toggle the slide or click in different places for each slideDown/slideIn?

Comment: You need to put quotes around the url in the link - it's being treated as a JS parameter `onclick="showslidey('<?php echo $link->link_id; ?'>,this)"` You should also consider url-encoding the link and also, attaching event handlers properly (what if you want click to do 2 things? setting the click attribute will clear the old one. Look into jQuery's `.click()` method)

Comment: Basically, when it slides down, i need the div class="header" to change to something like div class="header slideopen" or something to that effect. what i'm trying to accomplish is being able to use different CSS for when the slide is open and when it is closed.